# module-info not compiled unless package classes are compiled with the same command

Tags: java, javac, java-module, module-info, java-package

I've got a folder called `myModule`. Inside it, there's another folder called `myPackage` in which my `Main.class` exists.

Next to `myPackage` I have my `module-info.java` which I'd like to compile. First take a look at the folders hierarchy:

```
--  myModule
    --  myPackage
        --  Main.class
    --  module-info.java
```

The problem is when I want to compile my `module-info.java` with the following command:

```
javac module-info.java
```

I get the following error:

```
package is empty or does not exist: myPackage
```

But, when I put Main.java inside myPackage and then compile both files with the same command:

```
javac module-info.java myPackage/Main.java
```

the error disappears. I can't understand why this should happen?

Comment: Does `module-info.java` contain line `exports myPackage`? If yes, what is surprising that javac cannot find a nonexistent package?

Comment: The package is right there in the current directory with Main.class in it (Next to module-info.java itself)

Comment: It's there but if you run `javac module-info.java`, javac only knows about module-info and nothing else.

Comment: So, it doesn't matter which of the *.java files inside the package gets compiled as long as it informs the javac that such a package exist. Is that right? If yes, what if I want to export a package of which I don't have source codes?

Answer (score 2):

***TL;DR*** — A *module-info.java* file is not designed to be a stand-alone thing. It is designed to be part of a multi-source file compilation unit. A unit which includes the module descriptor, ***plus*** *at least* one other ***source*** file.

---

***The long-winded version***

> „*…there's another folder called `myPackage` in which my `Main.class` exists…*“

I'm gonna assume you meant to type *`Main.java`* and that *`Main.class`* is an oversight since…

1. You don't mention anything about it being an already-compiled byte code file.
2. I can't think of a reason why anybody would *intentionally* put a *.class* file in a source directory.

I'm also gonna assume — *although you didn't mention it at all in your question* — that you're intentionally following the convention recommended in the [*Project Jigsaw: Module System Quick-Start Guide*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start)…

> > „*…By convention, the source code for the module is in a directory that is the name of the module…*“

I've established that compilation would succeed if your *`myModule`* module is just an empty *`module{}`* block. That is, if it doesn't declare that it *`exports myPackage`*.  So I'm gonna also assume your *module-info.java*, like my experimental one, contains…

```java
module myModule { 
    exports myPackage;
}
```

Keep in mind what the *`javac`* tool [*is designed to do*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/javac.html#description)…

> > ***Description***
> >
> > *The `javac` command reads ***source files*** that contain module, package and type declarations written in the Java programming language…*

Also consider the [*reliable configuration goal*](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Emr/jigsaw/spec/) of the JPMS…

> > *Reliable configuration, to replace the brittle, error-prone class-path mechanism with a means for program components to declare explicit dependences upon one another*

If I sign a contract to mow your lawn every Saturday but then never turn up, how reliable am I? Imagine if it were legal for *`javac`* to compile a module-info.java file for a module that *claimed* to export a package, but that package had no classes in it. How *reliable* is such a module?

If my build downloaded your hypothetical *`myModule`* artifact from Maven Central, I could have an *`import myPackage.*`* in my class only to find there's nothing in it. What use is a package with nothing in it?

> „*The problem is when I want to compile my module-info.java with the following command:*“
>
> ```sh
> javac module-info.java
> ```

The clue to the mystery is the fact that the above command results in the same error when the *`myPackage`* directory contains legal source code.

The error message isn't telling you that the ***file system directory*** is empty. It's telling you that the ***package*** that you claim the module exports is empty. Empty as in: ***The compiler doesn't know anything about source code you never pass to it as part of a compilation unit***.

> „*…the error disappears. I can't understand why this should happen?…*“

By executing: *`javac module-info.java myPackage/Main.java`*, you're composing a compilation unit made up of the things the module declares it exports. Which is [*the way the JPMS documentation*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#greetings) specifies the system is *expected to be* used…

```sh
$ javac -d mods/com.greetings \
        src/com.greetings/module-info.java \
        src/com.greetings/com/greetings/Main.java
```

So typos notwithstanding, the cause of the error you report is pretty simple: ***Compiling a module that doesn't contain any source files is not only pointless, as far as the compiler is concerned it is a malformed module. Therefore, it's illegal.***

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so today I ran into this exact issue, and I had the same problem as you: I didn't have the source code. However, I discovered that `javac` doesn't require you to have the actual source code, just *a* java source file in each exported package.

My solution was to create a powershell script that makes a copy of the file hierarchy, adds dummy java files to each directory whose name is a valid java package name, and compiles it

```bash
# Initial folder heirarchy:
# 
# --  staging
# --  myModule
#     --  myPackage
#         --  Main.class
#     --  module-info.java

# copy folder hierarchy (without files) from myModule to staging
xcopy myModule\* staging /t /e

# don't forget to copy the module-info.java file
Copy-Item myModule/module-info.java staging

# Get an array of all directories in staging
$Packages = Get-ChildItem staging -Directory -Recurse

# Iterate over those directories
:packageLoop foreach ($Package in $Packages) {
    # Each dummy file needs a package declaration at the top, so this generates the package name
    $PackageName = ''
    $PackageDir = $Package
    while ($PackageDir.FullName -ne (Get-Item staging).FullName) {
        if (-Not ($PackageDir.Name | Select-String -Pattern '^[a-z$_][a-z$_0-9]*$' -Quiet)) {
            # skips over this directory if package name is invalid
            continue packageLoop
        }

        $PackageName = "$($PackageDir.Name).$PackageName"
        $PackageDir = $PackageDir.Parent
    }

    $PackageName = $PackageName.Substring(0, $PackageName.Length - 1)

    # Creates the dummy file Foo.java
    New-Item "$($Package.FullName)/Foo.java" -ItemType File -Value "package $PackageName ; public class Foo { }" | Out-Null
}

# Compiles entire staging directory, including module-info.java
javac -d staging (Get-ChildItem staging\* -Recurse -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)

# module-info.class can now be found at staging/module-info.class
```